# Missing data per site

Tags: missing-data, vcftools

I want to calculate statistics of missing data per each site in my vcf file.

Using vcftools --missing-site gives wrong stats for several sites.

Is there is any other way to calculate it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `plink --missing` you can calculate missingness per individual or per variant from a vcf file.